# Meteor/Blaze template $.Session

Tags: session, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm following a Meteor tutorial that is using $.Session.get in a Blaze template and it's not behaving as expected. The template is supposed to evaluate a session variable and either show a form or a button. If the button is clicked the session variable gets set to true and the form is supposed to appear. That's not happening.

I'm suspecting it's a Meteor/Blaze versioning problem, because there have been lots of changes recently. I'm using Meteor 1.4.2.1 and I'm pretty sure this tutorial was for Meteor 1.2.

Here is the template snippet:

```
<template name="Recipes">
{{ #if $.Session.get newRecipe }}
  {{> NewRecipe }}
{{ else }}
  <button class="new-recipe">New Recipe</button>
{{ /if }}...
```

I'm also using Meteor Toys and JetSetter and can see that the session variable has the value of 'true', so that value is correct. It's just not picking it up in the template.

Any pointers on this one?

Here is the package list:

```
meteor-base             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mobile-experience       # Packages for a great mobile UX
mongo                   # The database Meteor supports right now
blaze-html-templates    # Compile .html files into Meteor Blaze views
session                 # Client-side reactive dictionary for your app
jquery                  # Helpful client-side library
tracker                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming     library

standard-minifiers      # JS/CSS minifiers run for production mode
es5-shim                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers.
ecmascript              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code

kadira:flow-router
kadira:blaze-layout
erasaur:meteor-lodash
stolinski:stylus-multi
fortawesome:fontawesome
spiderable
fastclick
raix:handlebar-helpers
aldeed:collection2
aldeed:autoform
accounts-ui
accounts-password
matb33:bootstrap-glyphicons
zimme:active-route
gwendall:auth-client-callbacks
meteortoys:allthings
datariot:ganalytics
check
reactive-var
```

And here are the relevant code blocks:

```
// set the session var to false - hide the form, show the button
Template.NewRecipe.events({
  'click .fa-close': () => {
 Session.set('newRecipe', false);
  }
});

// set the session var to true - show the form, hide the button
Template.Recipes.events({
  'click .new-recipe': () => {
  Session.set('newRecipe', true);
  }
});
```

Comment: It would be useful to point to the tutorial you are using. It seems that some of the things you are using are only defined there.

Comment: Here you go, and I found part of the problem thanks to your suggestion. I didn't have quotes around the var name.

https://youtu.be/iYm1pbeYAm0?t=7m8s

Comment: Did you add the `raix:handlebar-helpers` package?

Comment: Yes, that package is included in the package list

Comment: No errors in console? Are you sure that the key is spelled correctly? Please post all of the relevant code, as this should work. Just to make sure, did you add the `session` package to your project?

Comment: Added code and package list. And no, there are no errors in the app web console or the shell where I started meteor.